# Angular 2 Router skips redirectTo and uses child route instead

Tags: angular, angular2-routing, angular2-router3

I've been tinkering with RC6 for a while now, hoping that finally routing to nested child components would work out of the box. Well, no such luck. The effect I'm seeing right now is that the `redirectTo` for the default route is just ignored and instead, Angular goes straight to the first child component.

```
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { LandingPageComponent } from 'src/landing-page.component';
import { DepartmentModule } from 'src/department/department.module';

const routes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'landing-page', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'landing-page', component: LandingPageComponent },
  { path: 'department', loadChildren: () => DepartmentModule }
];

export const appRoutingProviders: any[] = [];
export const routing = RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {enableTracing:true});
```

You should think entering no URL would take me to `landing-page`, but no, Angular picks `department` for reasons that are beyond me.

From that point everything works as expected, I can then navigate to a child route

```
import { Route, RouterModule } from '@angular/router';
import { DepartmentComponent } from './department.component';
import { DepartmentDetailsComponent } from './department-details.component';

const departmentRoutes: Route[] = [
  { path: '', component: DepartmentComponent },
  { path: ':id', component: DepartmentDetailsComponent }
];

export const departmentRouting = RouterModule.forChild(departmentRoutes);
```

The weird thing here though is, that I need

```
<a [routerLink]="['../..']">
```

to navigate 1 level back up. Possibly, both problems are related.

Does anyone have an idea what I'm missing? The [plnkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/4UPakVKr9rdQpYu5yTWr?p=preview) can be found here.

Comment: What is your expected behavior?

Comment: Does it load `landing-page` first which has a button(with redirect to dept 45)?

Comment: To arrive on `landing-page` if I don't provide a path, of course.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You just need to remove **DepartmentModule** from **imports**(**from AppMoule's @NgModule()**) as shown below,

```
imports: [ BrowserModule, MdButtonModule, 
           RouterModule, routing]         //<---removed DepartmentModule declaration
```

**working** : http://plnkr.co/edit/qoZ3YCwSz0mQ5o974Dt0?p=preview

Comment: And it fixes the `[routerLink]`as well, awesome!

Comment: Make sure not to import lazy loading module. They are meant for lazy loading. Angular2 will take care on its own.